# In PyQT4, how can I hide the window title of a child widget?

Tags: python, qt, qwidget

I am working in PyQT4 with Qt Designer. My goal is to hide the title bar of a widget.

I know there is a method like `widget.setWindowFlags` (`QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint`) or `widget.setWindowFlags` (`QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint`), but it doesn't work in my case.

My widget is a child of `QWorkspace`. That means my widget was added to `Qworspace`. I am trying to hide the title bar in the same way, but it doesn't work.

Does anybody knows how to remove the program's title bar in this case?

My Code: I tried with both methods. They have been commented out.

Edit:

**modul: search.py**

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget
from PyQt4.uic import loadUi
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Search_Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent, Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.getPath_search_ui = os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), 'files', "qt_ui", 'pp_search.ui')
        self.ui_pp_search = loadUi(self.getPath_search_ui, self)
```

**modul: mdi.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os

from PyQt4.QtGui import  QMainWindow, QWorkspace
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.uic import loadUi

from ..modules_ui.ui_pp_search import Search_Window


    class Mdi_Main(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

            self.getPath_mdi = os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), 'files', "qt_ui", 'pp_mdi.ui')

            self.ui_TestMainWorkSpace = loadUi(self.getPath_mdi, self)

            self.ui_TestMainWorkSpace.showMaximized()

            self.workspace = QWorkspace()
            self.workspace.setScrollBarsEnabled(True)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.workspace)

        def create_action_menu(self):
            self.ui_TestMainWorkSpace.actionSearch.triggered.connect(self.show_search_form)

        def show_search_form(self):
            search_form = Search_Window()
            self.workspace.addWindow(search_form, Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            search_form.show()
```

You can see I try to hide the title bar by adding search_form to workspace. Its also doesn't work.

Comment: A code snippet may clarify the problem and increase the likelihood of a response.

Comment: Where can I post a snippet code? Here in the comment-area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet works for me, by specifying the window flags to the [addWindow](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qworkspace.html#addWindow) method:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWorkspace, QTableView
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    workspace = QWorkspace()
    view = QTableView()
    workspace.addWindow(view, Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    workspace.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```